# Git-1.7.0.2 is getting my USERID in UPPERCASE

Tags: git, authentication, uppercase

I'm new to this program, and site,

OS Platform: Windows XP (x32-bit)

I have installed (Git-1.7.0.2) tool, and I would like to know if there is a way to make this program not to get my USERID in UPPERCASE.

At first, I was thinking it was coming from the registry, so, I did search for any entry that relates to my login, and for those that I found in UPPERCASE, I changed it to lower, then restarted my WinXP system.

Unfortunately, that has not resolved my issues, and it is important to be able to resolve this since that issue is not allowing me to login to our servers, etc.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Paste some of your .gitconfig (it should be under your home folder)

Answer (score 2):

Try entering these commands in a shell (GitBash?)

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@example.com"
```